# Cordova Plugin Add/Remove for windows on a Mac

Tags: ios, windows, cordova, plugins, installation

I am developing an app in Cordova that runs on iOS, Android, Windows and OSX.  Everything is fine until you have to add or remove plugins.  I develop the iOS, Android and OS X on a mac, and the Windows UWP on a windows machine.

When you try to add or remove a plugin you are stuck because on the mac I get the following error: "The platform "windows" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform." and fails.

When you try to add or remove a plugin on windows I get the following error: "The platform "android (or ios or osx)" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform." and fails.

Currently I remove windows from the platforms on the Windows computer, check the project in to github, check it out on my mac and and edit plugins for android/ios/osx then check it back in.  After that I pull on my Windows and re-add the platform.  The problem with this is cordova does not remember any images, app store associations, nuget packets etc making it a painstaking process that leads to many bugs.

Is there a way to ONLY add/remove a plugin on windows on the windows computer, and only for ios/android/osx on the mac and somehow make it all go together?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect this is happening because the platforms are not being successfully installed / removed. If you look in the `platforms/` folder, check to see that the platforms that are acting up actually have valid folder structure and contents. If this is the case you need to manually remove the platforms.

Instead of removing the windows platform and committing to git, you should consider using the `--nosave` option: `cordova platform remove windows --nosave`. This way the changes are not saved to your package.json or configuration.xml. This would allow you to make changes on OSX without having to constantly check in the removed windows platform.

Something that may help is using the cordova repository management tool that I have created: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-clean. This will help making sure all of the changes being made to the configuration are reflected in your current working directory across your machines / branches.

Comment: Thanks david, the platforms are being successfully installed but My mac cannot add/remove platforms or plugins for windows, and my windows cannot add/remove platforms or plugins for iOS/Android/OSX.  I think its a limitation of cordova?

Comment: This does not sound like proper behaviour, you should be able to remove platforms without issue / limitation. Consider re-installing the newest version of cordova and trying again. If this does not work I would try removing the platforms manually.